# My cockatiel gave birth to 4 babe in first cycle, need to take care of it, please educate me?

Tags: breeding, birds, cockatiels

I had a pair, and they hatched 4 chicks in first clutch

What would I need to know about care of the chicks?

Comment: It would be good to have a canonical answer to this.

Comment: Is your cockatiel feeding them? And are you wanting to hand raise them to be more handle-able?